# Iterate over polygons to convert WFS features

Tags: python, wfs, ogr2ogr

So my first question on stackexchance.

With ogr2ogr its possible to convert WFS features to SQlite with the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" OUTPUT.sqlite WFS:"INPUT_WFS_url"
```

It works. But there is a limit on the number ogr features to extract from the wfs. My idea is then to iterate over features in a shapefile containing polygons (index), and add the result to the output SQLite.

So the idea is to use `-clipsrc`, and use each feature from the index polygon as input. (it works whit a single polygon, but I don't know how to iterate). I have also tried to do it whit python without the right result.

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the limitation of the number of features to extract from the wfs, is a wfs limitation. But wfs (version 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0) all support STARTINDEX parameter as well as MAXFEATURES parameter (MAXFEATURES was replaced with COUNT in wfs 2.0) so you could iterate your function till you get everything from the wfs service

Comment: Paging does not belong to WFS 1.0.0 but some WFS servers do support it also with WFS.  If server supports paging you can configure GDAL to utilize it http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html with `OGR_WFS_PAGING_ALLOWED, OGR_WFS_PAGE_SIZE, and OGR_WFS_BASE_START_INDEX`